# Characterization of product of dual dual Hilbert spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X_i$ be Hilbert spaces and $X_i'$ its dual spaces, with $i=1,2$.

Let $F\in(X_1\times X_2)'$.

Prove that exists $F_1\in X_1'$ and $F_2\in X_2'$ such that

$<F,(x_1,x_2)>=<F_1,x_1>+<F_2,x_2>$ for all $(x_1,x_2)\in X_1\times X_2$,

where $<\cdot,\cdot>$ represents the respective duality pairing.

Comment: Define $F_1(x_1)=F(x_1,0)$ and $F_2(x_2)=F(0,x_2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x_1 \in H_1$ define 
$$ F_1(x_1) := \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<F, (x_1, 0)> $$
Then $F_1$ is linear, and we have 
$$ \left|F_1(x_1)\right| \le \left|\<F,(x_1,0)>\right|\le
\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm F\norm{(x_1,0)}
 = \norm F \cdot \norm{x_1} $$
Hence $F_1$ is bounded, that is $F_1 \in X_1'$. Analogously, we see that 
$$ F_2(x_2) := \<F, (0, x_2)> $$ 
defines an $F_2 \in X_2'$. By construction
$$ \<F, (x_1, x_2)> = \<F_1,x_1> + \<F_2, x_2> $$